# Looking for solution of a linear equation (which is a very important lemma in my research).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $M\geq 2$ and $1<\beta_i<2$, $1\leq i \leq M$ and the equation:

$h_1\beta_1^{L-1}+h_2\beta_1^{L-2}+\cdots+ h_{L-M-1}\beta_1^{M+1}=h_L+\beta_{1}^{L}$

$h_1\beta_2^{L-1}+h_2\beta_2^{L-2}+\cdots+ h_{L-M-1}\beta_2^{M+1}=h_L+\beta_{2}^{L}$

$\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots$

$h_1\beta_M^{L-1}+h_2\beta_M^{L-2}+\cdots +h_{L-M-1}\beta_M^{M+1}=h_L+\beta_{M}^{L}$

where $M\geq 2$ is an integer and $L$ is a lager integer that $L>2M+2$,  $h_1\,,h_2\,,h_{L-M-1}\,,h_{L}$ are variables.

Can we find a solution $(h_1\,,h_2\, \ldots,h_{L-M-1}\,,h_{L})$ such that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{L-M-1}|h_k|+|h_{L}|\leq 2$$?

Thank you for your discussion.

Comment: Are you looking for a formulation, or an algorithm given a specific value of the $\beta$ matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Your system is overdetermined if I understand correctly, and you wish to find a solution $\mathbf{h}$ with small norm. Your norm here is not the euclidean norm, and while the stricly minimum solutions between the two norms may differ, you may still benefit with using the euclidean norm over the norm given. I say that because least squares uses the euclidean norm.

Your system:
$$\pmatrix{\beta_1^{L-1} & \beta_1^{L-2} & \cdots & \beta_{1}^{M+1} & -1\\
  \beta_2^{L-1} & \beta_2^{L-2} & \cdots & \beta_{2}^{M+1} & -1\\
  \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots\\
  \beta_M^{L-1} & \beta_M^{L-2} & \cdots & \beta_{M}^{M+1} & -1}\pmatrix{h_1 \\ h_2 \\ \vdots \\h_{L-M-1} \\ h_L} = \pmatrix{\beta_1^L \\ \beta_2^L \\ \vdots \\\beta_{M}^L \\ }$$

This actually is somewhat similar to some of my own previous research. One hopefully helpful key term is called ridge regression. The explanation about ridge regression that I like follows.

Ridge regression basically extends the over-determined system to allow it to be solved with least squares. This is necessary as the least squares finds the best fit solution where there are no exact solutions. Your situation here is the opposite, there are many solutions. In matrix notation your system is
$$A\mathbf{h} = \mathbf{b}$$

If you extend it as such
$$ \left[\matrix{A & I}\right] \pmatrix{\mathbf{h} \\ \mathbf{t}} = \mathbf{b}$$
then you are "weighting" each equation equally. If you use something other than $I$ then the weighting is different. $\mathbf{t}$ is basically a dummy variable. The problem then becomes how to vary those two parameters for your desired results.

I believe this is an open problem, and I feel it is one that does have a solution. I could be wrong, maybe it is solved, but I haven't seen it unless it is written in one of the many publications that I can not understand. And if the solution does exist, it either solves some difficult lattice reduction problems, or does not discretize very well (it is much easier to find a least squares solution in a continuous field like the real numbers than it is to find a solution among integers only for example; that is the main difference between least squares and lattice reduction).

Comment: Actually, you have $M$ equations and $L-M> M+1$ variables, so you do have an undertetermined system... in which case there may not be a solution. And regular least squares would be the thing to look at for that.

Comment: :I think that there exists a solution, the key point is to find a special solution and the homogeneous equation has non-zero solutions, adding these solutions and we can find the general solution, from which we can choose the one that has small norm.

Comment: That does sound like a (somewhat) simple least squares problem. Pick any $y$ s.t. $Ay=b$, then define the subspace of any $x$ s.t. $Ax = 0$. Then find the nearest point between $y$ and the subspace. My intuition says that is do-able, but I have never tried it, nor read anything in the literature about it.

Comment: Actually, I have found a simple solution of my research, I do not need this strong version. Thank you for your discussion.

Comment: I went a bit off topic for your needs concerning ridge regression. Also, I use it in an odd way in order to deal with integer lattices. I am only recently learning about the use of SVD for your situation here; it is what is needed given specific values. Please post your solution when you get the chance.

Comment: sorry, I made a big mistake when I checked the algorithm again and found that there is a chance we can find a positive solution(all the coordination are positive),in my above question, the right side of equation system is $-h_{L}+\beta_i^{L}$ not all positive. if you can find a positive solution, then let $\beta_i$ tends to 1, then the norm condition can be achieved. Another idea is using the so-called Moore-Penrose inverse, which the least squares solution can be found.So my attention now is the positive solution, can you find the positive solution? I use this lemma in the fractal.

Comment: SVD gives you the Moore-Penrose, call it $A^+$. Using $A^+$ gives you the smallest possible solution if there are multiple solutions. If there are no solutions, then it gives you the closest solution. You say you have multiple solutions, so use it this way to find the smallest; $Ax=b \rightarrow x=A^+b$

Comment: Honestly, I am not familiar with the Moore-Penrose theory, what the sense of smallest solution? In my problem, I need the L^{1} norm not the euclidean norm.obviously, the rank of the matrix in my problem is M(the rank of row vectors), therefore, the equation system has non-zero solutions(actually, infinite solutions) moreover, the matrix is connected to the schur polynomial in the representation of algebra. Could you give me some references about the smallest solutions to the equation?

Comment: The minimum is within the euclidean norm. I was made aware of that without proof, but convinced myself by looking at the SVD form of the pseudo-inverse(Moore-Penrose). SVD is a unitary decomposition, and unitary decompositions are norm preserving. But the norm is as I stated the euclidean.